# Verifying Secugen fingerprint capture from database in android java

Tags: java, android, database, fingerprint, verify

0

I have working on a biometric sign-in project and I want to verify already captured database fingerprint image of fingerprint where someone can just tap the sensor and it verify with database fingerprint with emp number . I am doing it in android java and I would like to know how I can verify the above-mentioned feature.

Comment: Contact Secugen and ask them.